# SAP BusinessObjects Financial Consolidation Excel Add-In Automation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins, business-objects

I have a SAP BusinessObjects Web 7.5 Add-in in Excel 2007.

The add in itself is made up of a compiled `.xll` file (`CtExcelLinksWeb.xll`) and a number of dll's.

A bit of VBA shows the xll is registered, and all of its registered functions.

However, when I try to use one of these functions in VBA using `Application.Run()`, I get this error:

> Runtime 1004 - Macro may not be available or may be disabled.

I have tried registering the xll within the same `sub (Application.RegisterXLL ())` and upon registering a VBAProject called `CtEmpty.csv` is created.

I want to be able to automate the use of this add-in using VBA as it does long winded repetitive tasks, and then I can work on figuring out how to use the functions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are the DLLs on the PATH? It may be that Excel can't load the DLLs that the XLL is dependent upon. Dependency Walker (depends.exe) is a handy tool for troubleshooting this kind of issue.

Also, have you tried using File/Options/Addins to register the XLL, as well as VBA code?